# How to size the image in equal length in bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!--........PORTFOLIO..........-->
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="portfolio bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, voluptates.</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Resposive.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Threads</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Illustration</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="booking1.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Threads</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Illustration</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Resposive.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Threads</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Illustration</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>


</section>
```

how to size the image equally in bootstrap4 card system as i am using the images of different size so by this the card size is also increasing .

please help me out from this as i am not able to size the cards in equal manner as i am using grid system .

Answer (score 4):

you can`height` to you images with `!important` to prevent override. and set `object-fit: cover;`:

```
  .card-img{
   width: 100%!important;
   height: 200px!important;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

**see fiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/dhupq0m4/ 
you can use `media-query` to change `width`/`height` 
`media-query`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: tell me if you need more help

Comment: as you told to add the css in .card-img when am applying this card size is increased or decreased but in the card the image size is disturbing as one card image size is perfect but the other card image size is different.

Comment: try `object-fit: cover;` to `.card-img` and set `height: 70vw;` insted of set `width`

Comment: tell me if it is help

Comment: thanks for your help but when am applying object-fit:cover; then the image is slightly cut from the top but when i am doing it to mobile mode the its showing the good result.but in the web mode it creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Card size is not equal because it has not equal size content or equal size images. Force the image to be in equal height with "height" or you can crop images into equal height. Having image with equal height good because it will not destroy the look of image. If you force the image to take height then you will not have a good image look.